# apt update error: ubuntu jammy release does not have a jammy release file

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, ppa, update-manager

Ever since I installed ubuntu I have been recieving this error about a missing release file and therefore failed update. Please help

[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16NK4.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have two PPAs enabled, one from [Micah Lee](https://launchpad.net/%7Emicahflee/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and one from [Webupd8](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Both are completely empty, and should be removed with `ppa-purge`.